# How can I call a function within the foreach loop and avoid redeclaring error

Tags: php, foreach

> **Fatal error**: Cannot redeclare short_count() (previously declared in
>   `below-code`:22)
>   in
>   `below-code`
>   on line 20

```
<?php
require_once( './wp-blog-header.php' ); 
query_posts('&showposts=-1');

    if(have_posts()) {

        while(have_posts()) : the_post();

            $prmlks = '"'. get_the_permalink(). '",';
            $links = array( $prmlks );
            foreach ($links as $items) {
                $json_data = get_transient( 'cache_'. $id .'_tr' );
                if ($json_data === false) {
                    $id = get_the_ID();
                    $json = file_get_contents( 'http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&format=json&urls=' . $items . '&pretty=1' );
                    $json_data = json_decode($json, true);
                    set_transient( 'cache_'. $id .'_tr', $json_data, 3600 );
                }

                function short_count() {

                    $num = $json_data[0]['total_count'];
                    if(empty ($num) ) {
                        return 'n/a';
                    } else {
                    if( $num < 1000 ) return $num;
                    $x = round($num);
                    $x_number_format = number_format($x);
                    $x_array = explode(',', $x_number_format);
                    $x_parts = array('k', 'm', 'b', 't');
                    $x_count_parts = count($x_array) - 1;
                    $x_display = $x;
                    $x_display = $x_array[0] . ((int) $x_array[1][0] !== 0 ? '.' . $x_array[1][0] : '');
                    $x_display .= $x_parts[$x_count_parts - 1];
                    return  $x_display;
                    }

                }


                $short_count = short_count();
                echo $short_count;

}
        endwhile;

    }

?>
```

The question is: **how can I call a function within the `foreach` loop ?**

I want to keep the function within the `foreach` loop so as to get the dynamic variables..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you want to keep the function within the `foreach` loop, it isn't necessary. You could simply move the function outside of the loop and only change the following:

```
function short_count($data) {
    $num = $data[0]['total_count'];
    ...
}
```

In the `foreach` loop you can simply call the method as follows:

```
$short_count = short_count($json_data);
```

The `$json_data` is the only part that you use in your function that is created within the `foreach` loop, but outside of your `short_count` function. By passing it into your function as a parameter, you can now completely remove it from the `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 2):

Move your function out of the loop. You only need to declare it once, not multiple times, so it has no need to be in that loop. You can move the function to the top of your code (after the `require_once`) or even the bottom of your code (before `?>`) instead, and then you will not run into this redeclaration issue. You can call the function from inside the loop all you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have moved it out of the loop and placed it after `require_once` and it with the use of `$data` it works fine. thanks !!